# Python writing to JSON file adds extra brackets

Tags: json, python-3.x, discord.py

Part of a project I'm working on involves updating data in a JSON file to match a given birthday. This is my write code:

```
with open('files/{}.json'.format(ctx.guild.id), 'w+') as file:
    addData = {"usersbday":{str(user.id): combined}}
    data = json.load(file)
    data.update(addData)
    file.seek(0)
    json.dump(data, file, indent=4)
```

And my JSON (with the added bracket to the end):

```
{
"info": {
    "prefix": ".",
    "color": "0x76b04a"
},
"users": {
    "524251322823856149": "Paris"
},
"usersbday": {
    "524251322823856149": "august 5"
}}
}
```

The extra bracket gets added in when the updated birthday in `usersbday` has fewer characters—say, a change from `august 5` to `may 1`. Is there a way to avoid this when writing to the file, or do I just need to add in catch statements every time I write to the file just in case an extra bracket gets added? The same issue happens when I update the location in the `users` dictionary—my code is basically identical for that. Any ideas? Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simplest solution: Add `file.truncate()` immediately after `dump`ing the data (or after the `seek`, though this empties the file entirely, and you may as well write your new data first to limit how much gets discarded), which will remove any data beyond the data you've written.

This isn't specific to JSON, it's just how you say "wherever the file is currently pointing, trim the file to drop all data beyond it".

Comment: That did it! Thanks.